# Where does the 'override' qualifier go with trailing return types?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 has the new `override` qualifier which can be applied to member functions to assert that they override a virtual function in the base class. C++11 also allows trailing return types so functions can be declared as `auto f() -> return_type`. When I combine both these features, I don't know whether `override` goes before or after the `->`.

For example, suppose we have the following base class:

```
struct Base {
    virtual auto f () const -> int = 0;
};
```

The two possibilities for a derived class are:

```
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual auto f () const override -> int { return 0; } // Compiles on g++ 4.7.1
};
```

or

```
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual auto f () const -> int override { return 0; } // Compiles on clang++ 4.0
};
```

g++ 4.7.1 compiles the first version but fails on the second with

```
test.cpp:6:30: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
test.cpp:6:34: error: 'override' does not name a type
```

whereas clang++ 4.0 compiles the second one but fails on the first with

```
test.cpp:6:11: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type
  virtual auto f () const override -> int { return 0; }
          ^
test.cpp:6:3: error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'
  virtual auto f () const override -> int { return 0; }
  ^                       ~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:6:35: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  virtual auto f () const override -> int { return 0; }
```

Which of these compilers is actually doing the right thing according to the standard?

**Edit:** As Kerrek SB notes, this is [a bug in gcc (Bugzilla link)](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54849).

Comment: The issue is fixed in GCC 4.8 HEAD branch :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the standard, 8.4.1, a *declarator* for a function includes the *trailing-return-type*, and a class function definition contains "*declarator virt-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub>". The second one, *virt-specifier-seq*, is one of `final` or `override`, so those come *after* the trailing return type. (I.e. Clang gets it right.)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like somebody reported the bug. I'm editing my question with a link.

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
class I
{
    virtual auto Func() -> void = 0;
};

class C : public I
{
    auto Func() -> void override;
};
```

It works in gcc since 4.8.1:
https://godbolt.org/z/TbTTwa